# Is there a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\infty$ for all $x_0$ in some interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function with its domain in $\mathbb{R}$. Is there an example of $f(x)$ such that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\infty$$
for all $x_0$ in some interval?

Comment: No.in orden to make sense The Notion of LIMIT, The point must be accessible, that is, it must be an acumulation point.

Comment: @TitoEliatron could you add a formal proof of this? I'm not terribly experienced in RA, but it seems feasible that a sufficiently "hilly" function will have the desired behavior.

Comment: @TitoEliatron What are you talking about? If $x_0\in[a,b]$ then $x_0$ _is_ an accumulation point of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Ok. I see my misunderstanding. Sorry. I was think it on some regular function.

Comment: Relaten to this question, is there a function such that for any $x_0\in [a,b]$ there is a subsequence $(x_k^0)$ such that $x_k^0\to x_0$ and $f(x_k^0)\to x_0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes.**

While David C. Ullrich has given what seems to be a good answer, there's a fatal flaw. It assumes that $f$ is defined everywhere in some interval. The question, however, only says that the domain is in $\Bbb{R}$, and makes no other assertions.

**The function:**

In fact, there is a function $f$ which is defined on the rationals that has the property you want. In fact, it has the property that for all $x_0\in\Bbb{R}$ it has $$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)= \infty.$$

Define $f:\Bbb{Q}\to \Bbb{R}$ by $f(p/q)=q$, where $p/q$ is the expression of the rational number in least terms.

Then for any $n$, the set of points at which $f$ has value less than or equal to $n$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\Bbb{Z}$, which is a finite union of discrete subsets of $\Bbb{R}$, and hence itself a discrete subset of $\Bbb{R}$.

Thus every point of $\Bbb{R}$ has a punctured neighborhood disjoint from this set, and hence for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, and every $x_0\in\Bbb{R}$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $q\in \Bbb{Q}$ with $0<|x_0-q|<\epsilon$ $f(q) > n$. However, this is exactly what it means for 
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \infty.$$

Comment: Wrong argument at $0<|x-x_0|<\epsilon$. By definition, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\infty$ means $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \exists \epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)>n$ for all $x$ satisfying $|x-x_0|<\epsilon$ (not $0<|x-x_0|<\epsilon$).

Comment: @user300871 That's incorrect. If we defined it that way, then the limit of the function $g(x)=1/x^2$ for $x\ne 0$ with $g(0)=0$ wouldn't have that the limit at 0 is $\infty$. Limits of functions are usually defined by using punctured neighborhoods, so that the value of the function at the point doesn't influence the limit.

Comment: you're right, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that "domain in $\Bbb R$" means $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$: No. Say $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$. For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $$E_n=\{x\in[a,b]:f(x)\le n\}.$$Then $$[a,b]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z} E_n.$$Since $[a,b]$ is uncountable this shows that there exists $n$ such that $E_n$ is infinite. So $E_n$ has an accumulation point $x_0\in[a,b]$, and hence $f$ does not tend to infinty at $x_0$.

Comment: +1 very nice argument.